# Should I use a lexical directory handle with opendir in Perl?

Tags: perl

Almost universally when people post questions on SO (or elsewhere) about Perl and reading from files, if any code that involves an old-style open

```
open FH, ">file.txt" or die "Can't open for write, $!";  # OLD way, do not use!
```

gets yelled at for not using a lexical filehandle.  As we all know,

```
open my $fh, ">", "file.txt" or die "Can't open for write, $!"; # new hotness
```

is the proper way to open a file handle in modern Perl.  What about directory handles?  In a few recent SO questions, people have posed questions that involve [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html), and posted code like

```
opendir DIR, "/directory" or die "Can't get the directory, wtf?! $!"; # ???
```

The [perldoc pages](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) show

```
opendir(my $dh, $some_dir) || die "can't opendir $some_dir: $!";
```

as the example.

Should we be suggesting to folks to use a lexical directory handle for opendir as well?

Comment: It would be nice if `while(readdir $dir){...}` worked like `while(readline $file){...}`

Comment: While in this case, the perldoc example *does* do it "right", keep in mind that the examples need to stay focused.  Periodically, people suggest going through and adding lexical declarations or strict/warnings to the examples; this largely gets shot down because it really obscures the point of example code.  So, if the example had been opendir(DIRH, ...), that would not have been an argument against lexical dirhandles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely. The argument for lexical filehandles for directories is identical to that for files - scoping to the current namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, lexicals are preferred for `opendir` as well as `open`.

Answer (score 3):

When I get the chance, I will be fixing all of those examples in the perldocs. [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113) already uses the lexical handles in the fifth edition.